# Converting a data.frame to a list of data.frames by an aggregating value

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have this `data.frame`:

```
df = data.frame(chr=c("chr1","chr1","chr1"),start=c(1,2,3),end=c(11,12,13),strand=c("+","+","-"),tid=c("t1","t1","t2"),exon_id=c(1,2,1))
```

I'm looking for a function that would convert `df` to a `list` of `data.frame`s where the aggregating value is `df$tid`.

Without a function, for this toy example, it would be:

```
df.list = list(df[1:2,], df[3,])
```

Since `df$tid[1:2]` is t1.

Comment: most certainly agree with Tyler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `split`:

```
split(df, df$tid)
```

should do the trick.